# How can I make a Spring Validator to be detected and used automatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

I want to validate the JSON content of a POST request in my controller.
I use @NullValue annotations and a custom Validator for a conditional validation. The input is invalid if the attribute `type` is `A` and the attribute `name` is empty.
But I can't get the validator to work.

I have this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@Validated
public class OrderController {
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order) {
      // do something
    }
}
```

and this `Validator` for the `Order` class:

```
@Component
public class OrderValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Order.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        final var order = (Order) target;

        if (order.getType() == Type.A && Strings.isEmpty(order.getName())) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "name.required", "Name required for type A");
        }
    }
}
```

and `Order` class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderDto {
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private Type type;
}
```

If I send a POST request where `type` is null, I get HTTP status 400 (Bad request) as expected.

**But when I send a POST request with `type`=`A` and `name`=`null` the method returns HTTP 201 (Created). The `OrderValidator` is not executed.**
Breakpoints prove, that the `supports` and `validate` methods are not called. But I can inject a `OrderValidator` bean, which means the component was found by Spring Boot.

*The only work-around I found was to use this as controller, but this does not look feel right to me:*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@Validated
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private final OrderValidator orderValidator;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(orderValidator);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order, BindingResult result) {
      // evaluate bindingResult manually
      // do something
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have same issue and cant find solution for that

Comment: @I_AM__PAUL not yet :(